# Pegar conteúdo dentro de uma tag

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho esse script de playlist, nele eu queria que o nome do vídeo selecionado na playlist volta-se para tag P

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  video = $("#video");
  nome = $("#nome");
  init();

  function init() {
    current = 0;
    playlist = $("#playlist");
    tracks = playlist.find("li a");
    len = tracks.length;
    playlist.find("a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      link = $(this);
      current = link.parent().index();
      run(link);
    });
    $("#anterior").on("click", function(e) {
      current--;
      if (current == len) {
        current = 0;
        link = playlist.find("a")[0];
      } else {
        link = playlist.find("a")[current];
      }
      run($(link));
    });
    $("#proximo").on("click", function(e) {
      current++;
      if (current == len) {
        current = 0;
        link = playlist.find("a")[0];
      } else {
        link = playlist.find("a")[current];
      }
      run($(link));
    });
  }

  function run(link) {
    video.src = link.attr("href");

    nome.innerHTML = link.innerHTML

    par = link.parent();
    par.addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    video.load();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="nome"></p>
<video id="video" width="200px" controls class="player" src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">
 Video nao suportado
</video>
<div id="anterior">proximo</div>
<div id="proximo">anterior</div>
<ul id="playlist">
  <li class="active"><a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">Big Buck Bunny 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">Big Buck Bunny 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">Big Buck Bunny 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para pegar o nome no início, é só você pegar o valor, assim que a função `init()` for iniciada e colocar na tag `<p>`:

```
var nomevideo = $("#playlist .active").text();
$("#nome").text(nomevideo);
```

Obs: ele pega a tag `<a>` que está com a class `.active`, ou seja, ativa no momento.

E depois você pode adicionar dentro do evento de `click` dos links, para atribuir o valor na tag `<p>`, sempre que um link for clicado:

```
nomevideo = $(this).text();
$("#nome").text(nomevideo);
```

Quando você utiliza o array do `find()`, você não pode definir ele diretamente no find, é necessário definir em uma variável e depois executar:

```
tag_selecionada = $("a")[0];
link = playlist.find(tag_selecionada)
```

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
  video = $("#video");
  nome = $("#nome");
  init();

  function init(){
   var nomevideo = $("#playlist .active").text();
   $("#nome").text(nomevideo);
    current = 0;
    playlist = $("#playlist");
    tracks = playlist.find("li a");
    len = tracks.length;
    playlist.find("a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      link = $(this);
      current = link.parent().index();
      run(link);
      nomevideo = $(this).text();
     $("#nome").text(nomevideo);
    });
    $("#anterior").on("click", function(e) {
      current--;
      if(current < 0){
       current = 0;
      }
      if(current == len){
        current = 0;
        tag_selecionada = $("a")[0];
        link = playlist.find(tag_selecionada).attr('href');
        $("#video").attr("src", link);
        nomevideo = playlist.find(tag_selecionada).text();
      $("#nome").text(nomevideo);
      }
      else{
        tag_selecionada = $("a")[current];
        link = playlist.find(tag_selecionada).attr('href');
        $("#video").attr("src", link);
        nomevideo = playlist.find(tag_selecionada).text();
      $("#nome").text(nomevideo);
      }
      run($(link));
    });
    $("#proximo").on("click", function(e) {
      current++;
      if(current == len){
        current = 0;
        tag_selecionada = $("a")[0];
        link = playlist.find(tag_selecionada).attr('href');
        $("#video").attr("src", link);
        nomevideo = playlist.find(tag_selecionada).text();
      $("#nome").text(nomevideo);
      }
      else{
       tag_selecionada = $("a")[current];
        link = playlist.find(tag_selecionada).attr('href');
        $("#video").attr("src", link);
        nomevideo = playlist.find(tag_selecionada).text();
      $("#nome").text(nomevideo);
      }
      run($(link));
    });
  }

  function run(link) {
    par = link.parent();
    par.addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>teste</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <p id="nome"></p>
 <video id="video" width="200px" controls class="player" src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">
  Video nao suportado
 </video>
 <button id="anterior">anterior</button>
 <button id="proximo">proximo</button>
 <ul id="playlist">
   <li class="active"><a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">Big Buck Bunny 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">Big Buck Bunny 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">Big Buck Bunny 3</a></li>
 </ul>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: é melhor utilizar na segunda função, do jeito que está não funcionara nos botões, apenas se clicar na tag A

Comment: quais botões? você está se referindo as `div` anterior e próximo?

Comment: alterei o código para o funcionamento dos "botões", primeiro ao clicar ele pega o `href` da tag `<a>` e depois atribui um novo valor para o video, ou seja, altera o video, segundo o `href` da tag e ele já pega o texto dela e atualiza o o título `<p>`. Além disso, coloquei uma estrutura de condição, para se caso o valor for menor do que 0, ele retorna para 0, pois no seu código ao clicar em anterior ele diminuia para -1, por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

minha solução:

```js
function run(link) {
  video.src = link.attr("href");
  par = link.parent();
  par.addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
  title = $("#playlist .active").text();
  $(".nome").text(title);
  video.load();
  video.play();
  resetPlayer2();
}
```